# Legend not showing the full text

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Why upon running this the full legend is not shown, I only have the first letter, namely 'T':

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x_a, 15, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu_a, sigma_a)
l = plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--', linewidth=1.5)

plt.xlabel('Annual log returns')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.legend((l),('Theoretical pdf'),loc=1) # why is this not working
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are expected to pass in an *iterable* of strings, but you pass in just *one* string. A string is an iterable of strings too (it yields individual characters), which is why only the first character is used.

Use an actual tuple to pass in the labels:

```
('Theoretical pdf',)
```

(note the comma), or pass in a list:

```
['Theoretical pdf']
```